# Hibernate Update turns delete/insert in HSQLDB

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

Observed that while Hibernate issues an update query, in HSQLDB delete and insert queries are executed. It is weird. Due to that non-updated values are becoming null. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the following configuration in your hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

If this value is set to 'create', then instead of updation,re-insertion will take place.